# Internet explorer 8 scale issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to scale a div with an anchor tag inside in Internet Explorer 8. The div is:

```
<div class="toScale">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

In order to achieve this I am using the following style for the div:

```
.toScale {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=2, M12=0, M21=0, M22=2, SizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

The scaling is done correctly (it is twice as big) but the effective bounding boxes remain unchanged as if the scaling was not done. So, in order to click the anchor, I must click on the area where the anchor would be if it was not scaled, not on the scaled text.

I have tried different positioning styles for the div and even using a different syntax for the filter (the one with `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=2, M12=0, M21=0, M22=2, SizingMethod='auto expand')"`) but nothing solves this problem.

In Internet Explorer 7 the same code works fine without having this issue.

Has anyone an idea what might solve this issue in Internet Explorer 8 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
this mayfix 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=8" />
```